# Como construir um bundle reutilizável em symfony e gerenciável via composer

Tags: php, composer, symfony-2, bundle

Mesmo após ler as [melhores práticas para reuso de código no symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/bundles/best_practices.html) e pesquisar sobre o uso do [composer](https://tableless.com.br/composer-para-iniciantes/), ainda não consegui entender como na prática eu devo criar o meu bundle para ser reutilizável. Sei que da forma como eu faço não é a ideal e queria fazer da forma correta, mas estou tendo dificuldades para entender como devo fazer.

Hoje eu faço da seguinte forma:

1. Crio um projeto usando o modelo do symfony.

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition projects/symfony2 "2.8.*"
```

2. Crio um bundle com o namespace que eu quero

```
app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Vendor\Bundle\MeuModuloBundle --format=annotation
```

3. Altero no arquivo composer.json o nome do pacote, a descrição e adiciono as dependências que preciso (somente isso) e após, atualizo o composer para instalar as dependências.

```
composer update
```

4. Inicializo os bundles das dependências que coloquei no composer no AppKernel.php
5. Trabalho nas regras de negócio do meu Bundle (Vendor\Bundle\MeuModuloBundle)
6. Comito e está pronto o meu bundle.

Se eu precisar reusar o bundle eu adiciono o nome dele no composer (conforme eu tenha descrito no composer.json do (Vendor\Bundle\MeuModuloBundle) e executo o comando do composer update. (O satis armazena os pacotes)

---

O problema nisso tudo é que o código vai cheio de lixo, com a pasta app, src, da conflito com o appKernel e etc... porque na realidade ele é um trata como um projeto (porque eu fiz assim da forma errada para o que eu quero) eu quero na realidade reutilizar ele como um módulo, porém não sei como fazer ao certo, pois preciso criar um módulo mas quero poder usar o doctrine, route, fosrest e outros recursos que já estão prontos no symfony.

Como devo proceder para fazer certo?

---

As boas praticas exibem a estrutura de pastas que devem ser criadas para que o projeto seja compatível com o symfony uma das minhas dúvidas é como eu faria para criar um projeto limpo, por exemplo: Eu teria que criar uma estrutura padrão e não usar o modelo do symfony? onde eu colocaria os arquivos de configuração config.yml, parameter.yml,  AppKernel, como ficaria o composer.json, o autoload, app.php, app_dev.php, console e etc... usado hoje, ou ele seria substituído pelo que? essa é a questão em si.

Comment: Você está utilizando o Symfony 2.8 (dá para saber verificando o código que vc postou do comando composer), entretanto o a versao que vc leu sobre boas práticas do Symfony (pelo menos o link é link que está na pergunta) foi para a versão "current", que no momento que escrevo o comentário é a 3.2. A versão do Symfony 2.8 é diferente da versão 3.*, por isso recomendo ler as boas práticas para a versão que vc está a utilizar: https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/bundles/best_practices.html

Comment: @FilipeMoraes Obrigado pelo comentário. As melhores praticas exibem a estrutura de pastas que devem ser criadas para que o projeto seja compatível com o symfony a versão 2.8 e 3.2 nesse aspecto não influencia muito, pois a minha dúvida é como eu faria para criar um projeto limpo, por exemplo: Eu teria que criar uma estrutura padrão e não usar o modelo do symfony? onde eu colocaria os arquivos de configuração appKernel usado hoje, ou ele seria substituído pelo que? essa é a questão em si.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está bem perto de criar um `Bundle` corretamente, o seu único problema pelo que pude perceber é uma noção clara das dependências e de onde colocar os arquivos.

## Dependências

O `composer` sempre irá gerenciar suas dependências, portanto no momento do desenvolvimento, você está fazendo correto em instalar tudo e prosseguir. Quando for disponibilizar seu `Bundle`, você deve remover a pasta `vendor/`.

Quando for baixar o pacote, no seu caso do Satis, o composer vai ler o arquivo `composer.json` do seu `Bundle` e vai resolver as dependências que estiverem faltando. Deste modo, você pode usar qualquer biblioteca que desejar, bastando apenas adicionar ao `composer.json`.

## Estrutura de pastas

A estrutura de pasta também é bem simples. Por padrão os desenvolvedores de bibliotecas colocam tudo na pasta `src/` e suas sub-pastas. Você é livre para utilizar a estrutura que desejar.

Um ponto importante a se pensar é sobre arquivos de configurações e demais propriedades. Como você mencionou que carrega algumas configurações, vou assumir que você está colocando o arquivo `minha_config.yml` na pasta `app/config/minha_config.yml` e que seu `Bundle` depende de algumas informações que estão nele para funcionar.

Se for este o seu caso, você deve carregar as configurações dinamicamente através de um leitor de configurações. Não vou detalhar todo o processo para não ficar uma resposta muito extensa, mas você pode ver na documentação oficial neste [link](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/bundles/extension.html).

## AppKernel

Caso o seu `Bundle` dependa de outros para funcionar e, consequentemente, estarem registrados no `appKernel` você terá que transferir esta responsabilidade aos usuários do seu pacote.

**Por exemplo**: Digamos que eu estou desenvolvendo o `TutorialBundle` que depende do `NinjaProgrammingBundle`. Enquanto eu estiver desenvolvendo e testando eu posso registrar o `NinjaProgrammingBundle` no `appKernel.php` do meu `Bundle` sem problemas.

Quando disponibilizar o `TutorialBundle` para outros usuários, você deve adicionar na documentação alguma informação dizendo que você necessita que o `NinjaProgrammingBundle` esteja registrado antes do seu.

Espero ter lhe ajudado.